# Critique about cocos2d-x coding style - C-style casts vs static_cast

Tags: c++, casting, cocos2d-x, static-cast

In [cocos2d-x source code](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/dd/d69/_c_c_object_8h.html) there is some code that handles member function pointers, shown below.

```
...
#define     menu_selector(_SELECTOR)   (SEL_MenuHandler)(&_SELECTOR)
...
typedef void(CCObject::*    SEL_MenuHandler )(CCObject *)
...
```

The Idea I gather is to use `menu_selector(<MyClass>::<MyFunction>)` to get a compatible function pointer. But **I believe the use of C style casts allows them to perform unsafe casts, and leading to possible undefined behavior**. Am I wrong here?

Just now a colleague of mine had an issue with the  below code

```
class HelloWorld:public CCObject{

    void function();

}

....., menu_selector(HelloWorld::function)); //last arg to another function call
```

This code gave illegal conversion error on VS2010, since a `CCObject *` parameter is required, **but not on IOS or Android compilers** (am not sure how old are the mobile compilers). I myself tested this with some similar code and in fact got it to compile with VS2010..

What I am asking is, is there a reason `cocos2d-x` is using `(TYPE)` instead of `static_cast<TYPE>`? `static_cast` would have blocked all such illegal casts. Is it because `static_cast` would block conversion from `(HelloWorld::*...)` to `(CCObject::*...)`?

Edit: Conversion of derived class function pointer to base class function pointer by `static_cast` [seems to be legal](http://liveworkspace.org/code/7O0NO%246), so am clueless as to why they choose `(TYPE)`.

Comment: I don't know why they chose C style casts (habit? cross-platform compatibility?). I do know that in C++ it's best practice to avoid C casts since there are better alternatives. This is something you should ask the devs on their forum, they're the ones who should know. ;)

Comment: are you sure. I remember when I using it like your sample. I did have compiler error report something like it is expect a void bla ( CCObject*) instead of void bla (void).